# Execute a procedure if none of the switch cases are satisfied?

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
switch (x) {
case 'a':
//do stuff
break;
case 'b':
//do stuff
break;
case 'c':
//do stuff
break;
}
```

I've been trying to solve and search solutions up for an hour, so far, no luck! :(

So, if none of these cases are satisfied, how do I make it do something else?
E.g., if x is not "a", "b" or "c", then I want it to do something. What is the best way round of doing that? I hope this makes sense and thank you everybody!

Comment: Add `default`: *" The default section handles all values that are not explicitly handled by one of the case sections."*

Comment: Use `default`?! Such things are described in most anything found by searching for "java switch".

Comment: There are 3 answers - exactly the same.

Comment: Another question that shows lack of effort from OP...

Answer (score 3):

Use the `default` case, this is exactly what its for...

```
switch (x) {
case 'a':
    //do stuff
    break;
case 'b':
    //do stuff
    break;
case 'c':
    //do stuff
    break;
default:
    //do what you want to do if none of the other cases fire
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! I love you all!

Comment: You'll see a checkmark beside it, just click it

Answer (score 1):

use default case  in switch

```
switch (x) {
case 'a':
//do stuff
break;
case 'b':
//do stuff
break;
case 'c':
//do stuff
break;
default: 
   //do here code
}
```

**note:** The default section handles all values that are not explicitly handled by one of the case sections., but it can be any where in switch. If default is not at end then use `break;` like you uses with other

Answer (score 1):

```
char x = 'z';
        switch (x) {
        case 'a':
        //do stuff
        break;
        case 'b':
        //do stuff
        break;
        case 'c':
        //do stuff
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("do somthing else");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default keyword, say you wanted to do a specific action when a 1 or 2 is passed in and print "another number" when a number other than 1 or 2 is passed in

```
    switch(i) {
        case 1:
            //Do something and break
        case 2:
            //Do some other thing and break
        default:
            System.out.println("Another number");
            break;
```